# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base58'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit version OS I am trying to run my program which convert hex to wif.
I used the command `python3 hex_to_wif.py` to run the program.
Then it showed the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hex_to_wif.py", line 1, in <module>
   
 import base58

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base58'
```

Then I used this command

`sudo pip install base58`

and it show this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: base58 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `python3` to run your program, then you should use `pip3 install PACKAGE` to install a package. As you are on Ubuntu, you have to be especially careful with that, because python2 is installed by default on your machine, and the `python` or `pip` command are probably using Python2.

*If using the `pip3` command is not enough :*

Sometimes, when you have multiple versions of Python installed (with multiple Python 3.X versions), using `pip3` is not enough, as it does not necessarily install a package for the latest version of Python installed on your machine.
You can check what version of python your `pip3` is using by using the `pip3 --version` command.

If you plan to run some code with Python 3.8 and need to install a package for this specific version of Python, you can use:

`pip3.8 install PACKAGE` or
`python3.8 -m pip install PACKAGE`

Then you can run your program using

`python3.8 YOURFILE`

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. Its work and my issues solve. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
python3 -m pip install base58
```

Because you are using `python3` to run, it use the same for installing the package